# How can the mouse be moved programatically in Common Lisp?

Tags: common-lisp, mouse

The code should run on Windows 10. I tried [asking on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/lisp/comments/be6plz/programmatic_control_of_mouse/), but the ideas are Unix/Linux only. There's also CFFI, but I didn't understand how to use it for this problem (the main usability part of [the documentation I found](https://common-lisp.net/project/cffi/manual/cffi-manual.html) is just an elaborate example not related to this problem).

I also looked through the SetCursorPos of Python, and found that it calls ctypes.windll.user32.SetCursorPos(x, y), but I have no clue what that would look like in CL.

And finally, there's CommonQt, but while there seems to be QtCursor::setPos in Qt, I couldn't find the CL version.

Answer (score 3):

The function called by the Python example seems to be [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setcursorpos). It is part of a shared library `user32.dll`, which you can load with CFFI,

```
(ql:quickload :cffi)

#+win32
(progn
  (cffi:define-foreign-library user32
    (:windows "user32.dll"))
  (cffi:use-foreign-library user32))
```

The `#+win32` means that this is only evaluated on Windows.

Then you can declare the foreign `SetCursorPos`-function with `CFFI:DEFCFUN`. According to the documentation, it takes in two `int`s and returns a `BOOL`. CFFI has a `:BOOL`-type, however the Windows `BOOL` seems to actually be an `int`. You could probably use cffi-grovel to automatically find the typedef from some Windows header, but I'll just use `:INT` directly here.

```
#+win32
(cffi:defcfun ("SetCursorPos" %set-cursor-pos) (:boolean :int)
  (x :int)
  (y :int))
```

I put a `%` in the name to indicate this is an internal function that should not be called directly (because it is only available on Windows). You should then write a wrapper that works on different platforms (actually implementing it on other platforms is left out here).

```
(defun set-cursor-pos (x y)
  (check-type x integer)
  (check-type y integer)
  #+win32 (%set-cursor-pos x y)
  #-win32 (error "Not supported on this platform"))
```

Now calling `(set-cursor-pos 100 100)` should move the mouse near the top left corner.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems here:

1. How to move the mouse in windows
2. How to call that function from CL.

It seems you have figured out a suitable win32 function exists so the challenge is to load the relevant library, declare the functions name and type, and then call it. I can’t really help you with that unfortunately.

Some other solutions you might try:

1. Write and compile a trivial C library to call the function you want and see if you can call that from CL (maybe this is easier?)
2. Write and compile a trivial C library and see if you can work out how to call it from CL
3. Write/find some trivial program in another language to move the mouse based on arguments/stdin and run that from CL