# Finding ltk window position

Tags: window, common-lisp, ltk

Is it possible to get the position of a ltk (Common Lisp basic GUI library) window (one of its corners), in pixels from the top left screen corner?

I'm trying to use mouse movement to control an applet I'm making ([details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55405140/common-lisp-mouse-position-with-ltk) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55736410/how-can-the-mouse-be-moved-programatically-in-common-lisp)), but I can only find the mouse's position relative to the window, and I can only set it relative to the screen itself. I want to hide the cursor and return it to a fixed point after every move, noting how it has moved. I need to know the window position to correct for the different measurements.

Comment: Maybe reach to tcl/tk experts and then we can transpose the answers to ltk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [manual](http://www.peter-herth.de/ltk/ltkdoc.pdf) gives several options for manipulating the toplevel, such as moving the window around or finding its position and dimensions. The particular expression needed here is (geometry *tk*), which returns a list of the window's x and y position and size.